# How do I use add user and modify the text files that have already been created on a bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to bash and I'm confused on how to write this?

I was given two txt files and I'm supposed to use one txt file to generate into the second txt file. How would I do this?

The first txt file is called `cs.roster.txt` it looks like this:

```
   CMPSC 1513 03|doejan|Doe, Jane|0510|0350
   CMPSC 1513 03|smijoh|Smith, John|0510
   CMPSC 1133 01|cp2stu3| CPII, Student3 Neither|2222|0020
```

The second txt file is called `new_user.txt` it looks like:

```
doejan:x:uid:gid:Doe,Jane+222222:/home/STUDENTS/majors/doejan:/bin/bash
smijoh:x:uid:gid:Smith,John+111111:/home/STUDENTS/nonmajors/smijoh:/bin/bash
```

We are working with useradd so this is a section of the code that I was working on but I don't know how or where add the `cs.roster.txt` file.

To word things better, I'm trying to add my `cs.roster.txt` file to the file called `new_user.txt`

The code below only reads the `new_user.txt` file while I want to read both.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  username=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f1)
  GECOS=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f5)
  homedir=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f6)
  echo "adduser -g '$GECOS' -d '$homedir' -s /bin/bash '$username'"
done < "new_user.txt"
```

How could I incorporate both?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for very nice post(having efforts in form of code and samples of input and expected output are there also), kudos and keep it up. Now 1 minor question to you: Do you really have these starting spaces in your file OR they are only copy/paste issue in your question?

Comment: The starting spaces. On the assignment, it just says input: cs.roster.txt output:new_user.txt. I'm honestly not sure what my professor is wanting, they haven't given any feedback. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: I created those txt files for testing purposes but they specified the name of the file and what they wanted for the input and what would be the output. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Ok, could you add expected output in CODE TAGS in your question and let us know then, it will make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Sorry but your expected output is still not clear, you want to compare 2 files is what I understood but by comparing which exact values and getting which exact output is still not clear.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I want the first txt file to have ':' instead of '|' and then read the different sections. @RavinderSingh13